# iterating through files in a directory to split them into 60 seconds audio files

Tags: audio, split, iteration

I have a big data set of an audio collection and I would like to split them into audio files of 60 seconds chunks, and ignore the ones that are not 60. 
How can I process on this while iterating the same function over all the directory ?

Comment: ffmpeg can do such dicing and slicing

Comment: using commands in terminal or with a python code ?